# Stein factorization $X\to B'\to B$ and $k(B')$ is algebraically closed in $k(X)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is from Shaferavich's Algebraic geometry II, cohomology of algebraic varieties, surface, p.137:

[image]

<strike>My question is: given a Stein factorization $X\xrightarrow{f'} B'\to B$, why $k(B)$ is algebraically closed in $k(X)$? From the factorization, I can see $k(X)=k(B')$ by $f_*'\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_{B'}$ and $k(B')/k(B)$ is a finite field extension by $B'\to B$ is finite. So I can see $k(X)/k(B)$ is a finite field extension, but I have not clue why $k(B)$ is algebraically closed in $k(X)$? Also I am not sure about the meaning of "$k(B)$ is algebraically closed in $k(X)$", does that mean there are no finite extensions of $k(B)$ belonging to $k(X)$?</strike>

Thanks for Mohan pointing out that it should be $k(B′)$ is algebraically closed in $k(X)$, so now my question is: why $k(B')$ is algebraically closed in $k(X)$?

Comment: It is probably a typo. What he means is $k(B')$ is algebraically closed in $k(X)$, not $k(B)$.

Comment: @Mohan sorry, but don't we have $k(X)=k(B')$ by $f_*'\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_{B'}$?

Comment: In your situation, $k(X)$ has transcendence degree one over $k(B')$. Think of the trivial example, $f:\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^1$, projction to one factor.

Comment: @Mohan thanks and I fixed my question, can you take a look and give an explanation?